# 'include' data from two tables with same column name in single query

Tags: parse-platform

I have two tables(Reviews and Comments) with same column name `userId`, how can i differentiate them in parseQuery so i may get the data using the 'include' option, query is as follow:

```
query.whereEqualTo("businessId", parseBusiness);
query.include("userId"); // from the reviews table
query.include("lastComment");
query.include("userId"); // from he comments table
```

`userId` is a pointer to the User table

Comment: On what table this query?

Comment: as they are two tables, while querying you will mention name of table right.. like ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("MyClass"); -- MyClass your table/class name in parse.com